# Vários UPDATES no banco de dados Firebird

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, sql-update

Eu consigo criar um método que realize diversos *updates* no banco de dados Firebird? Por exemplo, quero atualizar os seguintes registro, mas teria que ser um por vez, tem como atualizar de outra maneira?

```
UPDATE TVENPEDIDO SET NOTAFISCALSERVICO ='18593'WHERE CODIGO = '0000523'
UPDATE TVENPEDIDO SET NOTAFISCALSERVICO ='18594'WHERE CODIGO = '0000516'
UPDATE TVENPEDIDO SET NOTAFISCALSERVICO ='18595'WHERE CODIGO = '0000513'
UPDATE TVENPEDIDO SET NOTAFISCALSERVICO ='18596'WHERE CODIGO = '0000082'
UPDATE TVENPEDIDO SET NOTAFISCALSERVICO ='18597'WHERE CODIGO = '0000571'
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Essencialmente não tem. Não há nada padronizado neste código que possa fazer ele ficar genérico (não há um critério aparente do que provoca o que), é tudo individual mesmo. Mas se puder reescrever esse código de outra forma aí quem sabe dê para fazer alguma coisa, mas só você sabe disto.

Só dá medo um código que faça isto, em geral é gambiarra já que trata de itens específicos literalmente. A não ser que o código não seja este.

Comment: Tem uma maneira sim amigo, já descobri.

Comment: Basta copiar o código, ir até o script execute e por no final de cada linha um ";" e marcar a opção use current connect

Comment: @EduardoTeixeira utilizando a mesma conexão apenas deixa a conexão aberta para executar várias comandos em sequencia, mas não utiliza o mesmo método para executar diversos updates. Ou todos aqui entendemos errado sua pergunta.